# Resize SDL2 window?

Tags: c++, window, sdl, sdl-2

Just made the jump from SDL1.2 to SDL2, been converting my code but couldn't figure out how to resize the window. Here's the code I have now:

```c
SDL_DestroyWindow(Window);
Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, ScreenSizeX, ScreenSizeY, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(Window);
```

Which as you can see just destroys the window and creates a new one. Sloppy but it works. What I want is to just resize the window, is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may look at the wiki doc: [SDL_SetWindowSize](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowSize)

Answer (score 30):

I believe that that you could use the SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE flag in SDL_CreateWindow to make the window resizable.

Answer (score 14):

To resize a window in SDL, first set it with the flag `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE`, then detect the resizing window event in a switch and finally call `glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight)`.

In the `switch`, use the flag `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` if you want only the final size of the window or `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED` if you want all the sizes between the first and the final.

To finish, update your own camera with the new window width and height.

```
m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("INCEPTION",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    m_windowWidth, m_windowHeight,
    SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);


switch (m_event.type) {

    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:

        if (m_event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {
            logFileStderr("MESSAGE:Resizing window...\n");
            resizeWindow(m_event.window.data1, m_event.window.data2);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


void InceptionServices::resizeWindow(int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {
    logFileStderr("MESSAGE: Window width, height ... %d, %d\n", windowWidth, windowHeight);
    m_camera->resizeWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: Why call `SDL_SetWindowSize` with the current size of your window?

Comment: `SDL_SetWindowSize` is called in `void InceptionServices::resizeWindow(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)` with the size of the resized window `m_event.window.data1` and `m_event.window.data2` given by SDL in the switch.

Comment: Yes, but the window will be resized automatically. You don't need to call `SDL_SetWindowSize` for it to be resized.

Comment: It made sense to me for completeness, I guess, but I agree that SDL resizes the window automatically, so I just removed the line `SDL_SetWindowSize(m_window, windowWidth, windowHeight);`.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
Window = SDL_CreateWindow(
  "Test",
  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
  ScreenSizeX,
  ScreenSizeY,
  SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
);
```

Use this function call